# A new maximality principle and its consequences

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Let us consider the following maximality principle:

**$(MP_*):$** For all uncountable regular cardinals $\kappa, 2^{<\kappa}=\kappa^{+}$
and all trees of height and size $\kappa$ are specialized.

It is easily seen that the principle implies the following:

1) There are no inaccessible cardinals.

2) For all infinite cardinals $\kappa, 2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$.

3) There are no $\kappa$-Souslin trees, for all uncountable regular cardinals $\kappa.$

Also using ideas of Todorcevic (see  [Some combinatorial properties of trees](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/blms/14.3.213/abstract;jsessionid=142B4DAA42039FAD433B2EB72EE79C97.f03t03)) one can show that the $(MP_*)$ implies the following:

4) If $P$ is a non-trivial forcing notion and if it adds a fresh subset of an uncountable regular cardinal $\kappa,$ then $P$ collapses $\kappa$ or $\kappa^+.$

> **Question 1.** Is $(MP_*)$ consistent?

Recall that the Foreman's maximality principle says that any non-trivial forcing notion either adds a new real or collapses some cardinals.

> **Question 2.** Does $(MP_*)$ imply the Foreman's maximality principle?

What other non-trivial consequences $(MP_*)$ has?

**Remark 1.** A tree $T$ of size and height $\kappa^+$ is called special
if there exists $f: T \to \kappa$ such that $f(t)=f(u)=f(w)$ and $t \leq_T u, w$ implies $u \leq_T w$ or $w \leq_T u.$

**Remark 2.** By results of Todorcevic and independently Baumgartner, ($MP_*$) is consistent for $\kappa=\aleph_1.$ On the other hand, shelah and I have proved its consistency for successor a regular cardinal.

Comment: I am confused. If $\kappa=\tau^+$, then the condition in $(MP_*)$ gives $2^\tau=\tau^{+3}$.

Comment: You are right, I edited it.

Comment: If we view $\kappa$ itself as a linear order, then it is a tree of height and size $\kappa$, but it cannot be special. Doesn't this show that $\text{MP}_*$ is inconsistent?

Comment: No, I don't take such objects as trees, I may also say that by special tree I mean something a little different. See Todorcevic's paper mentioned above in which the consistency of the statement for $\aleph_1$ is stated. For higher successors of regulars, Shelah and I have proved the consistency of the statement.

Comment: See statement (C) in his paper.